# Java hardcode string object from database

Tags: java

basically I have a object from the databsae that I'm setting to a string and passing to a webservice.

This works fine.  However I want to hardcode that string in a class from the database to do some unit testing.

Problem is...the string has ""'s in certain places that is necessary in the WS.  I know I can manually change all these to ''s then enclose the whole string in "", but is there a utility that will do that for me?

```
string test =    {

"testMap": {
"test1": "",
"test2": "blah",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try looking for a Java Library to encode JSON, thats probably the better longer term strategy.

If you are talking about just formatting that string, just do a find (") and replace (\") to escape the "?

```
    String test =    "{ " + 
            "\"testMap\": { " +
            "\"test1\": \"\", " +
            "\"test2\": \"blah\", " +
             " }" +
            "}";
//output
{ "testMap": { "test1": "", "test2": "blah",  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils

String output = org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(input)

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify this python script, it removes all whitespaces from text.

```
import re

x = u"abc   de\t  \tf"
print x  # abc   de     f
y = re.sub(r"\s+", u",", x)
print y  # abc,de,f
```